# How to inject a variable with Liquid?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How does one inject a variable into a html file with Liquid?

Here's the original code.

```
<!-- post list -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <li>
    <!-- Post Summary -->
    <!-- <a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">
      <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    </a> -->

    {%- include post-summary.html -%}

  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's how i'd like to refactor it...sorta

```
<!-- post list -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <li>
    {%- include post-summary.html -%}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<!-- Need Mechanism to Inject 'post' -->
<!-- Post Summary -->
<a href="{{post.url | prepend: site.baseurl}}">
  <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described [in the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameter-variables-to-includes), you can pass, in Jekyll, variables to an included file.

So in your case:

```
<!-- post list -->
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <li>
    {%- include post-summary.html post=post -%}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<!-- post summary -->
<a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
  <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
</a>
```